# Using variable to assign value to where clause of lookup transformation

Tags: ssis

I have a DataFlow Task which picks up a variable while running. This variable changes its value three times so the job has to run three times. I want to have a Lookup Transformation in the DFT that checks if the new value to be inserted already exists in the database for the value of the current variable.(I cannot create any unique key constraints in the database.)How do I make the where clause of the LookUp transformation pick up the value from the variable? I cannot use execute sql as it is restricted to Control flow tasks.

Answer (score 0):

A better way than use a lookup is to use a MERGE statement : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

If you still want to use a lookup, you have to disable the cache on your component (or set it to partial), then in the advanced tab you can check the "Modify SQL instruction", type your query and use variables using the "parameters..." button.

Comment: I am using SSIS 2005.I did what you said but the parameter window doesn't display variables.

Comment: Do you mean Merge Dataflow task?

Comment: Can I use @[User::VariableName] in the lookup?

Comment: for merge, I meant MERGE T-SQL Statement, as my link points. I do not have access to BIDS 2005, but as I recall you can add parameters in the advanced section. Sorry, can't help much more without access to same BIDS as you.